# How to detect if CWnd* is CListCtrl or CEdit ...?

Tags: mfc

In my program I run on all childs of my dialogs and set their properties according to type of control but how can I detect **type of control** from `CWnd*`?

Comment: [Accessing Run-Time Class Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/accessing-run-time-class-information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the control isn't subclassed you need to determine the type before you can subclass it. The WinAPI function `GetClassName` will help you.

If the window is already subclassed and you get a `CWnd` by any other function you can use `pWnd->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CEdit))` method to test if it is a `CEdit` window. Same is possible for `CListCtrl` or any other class.

Comment: "_If the window is already subclassed_" then standard C++ `dynamic_cast` works aswell.

Comment: problem is in ClistCtrl GetClassName return "AfxWnd%%" depend to version of VS or debug release mode

Comment: No. A CListCtrl window will always return a classname WC_LISTVIEW